# Error in select no header

Tags: abap

I want make select from `EPREI` to `ET_DATA ET_DATA` have prices prices is structure what i want fill it from `EPREIH`...

```
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Lokálne rozhranie:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(I_PREIS) TYPE  ZRT_IWP_CPREISTYP OPTIONAL
*"  EXPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(ET_DATA) TYPE  ZTT_IWPIFC_PRICE
*"  EXCEPTIONS
*"      NO_DATA_SELECTED
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

 field-symbols: <lfs_ET_DATA> like line of ET_DATA.
 refresh ET_DATA.

 SELECT *
  FROM EPREI
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ET_DATA.

 loop at ET_DATA assigning <lfs_ET_DATA>.
   select *
 from EPREIH 
   into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ET_DATA-prices
   where PREIS = <lfs_ET_DATA>-PREIS
   and PREISTYP <= <lfs_ET_DATA>-PREISTYP.
 endloop.
```

it shows error:

`"ET_DATA" is table without hedaer line and therefore have not component call prices.`

How can i make this select correctly? Sorry for my english but i am so tired...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the previous answer said, ET_DATA is a reference to a table type and does not have a work area.

So if you really want to add a list of EPREIH into ET_DATA-PRICE you have to point to the work area which is assigned to your field symbol.

Something like this:

```
 field-symbols: <lfs_ET_DATA> like line of ET_DATA.
 refresh ET_DATA.

 SELECT *
  FROM EPREI
  into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ET_DATA.

 loop at ET_DATA assigning <lfs_ET_DATA>.
   select *
 from EPREIH 
   into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE <lfs_ET_DATA>-prices
   where PREIS = <lfs_ET_DATA>-PREIS
   and PREISTYP <= <lfs_ET_DATA>-PREISTYP.
 endloop.
```

extra tip: try using pretty printer with "keywords uppercase" and avoid "select *" if you are not using all fields from those tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying, but it looks like you want to update the field "prices" of table ET_DATA.

If you have 1 record in EPREIH for each record in EPREI, your select should look like this :

```
loop at ET_DATA assigning <lfs_ET_DATA>.
   select single prices
   from EPREIH 
   into <lfs_ET_DATA>-prices
   where 
     PREIS = <lfs_ET_DATA>-PREIS
     and PREISTYP <= <lfs_ET_DATA>-PREISTYP.
 endloop.
```

You are using a field (ET_DATA-prices) as a table (INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF).  That will not work.

Comment: hmmm i WAnt ET_DATA-preis fill by coresponding data from EPREIH. ET%DATA is standart price and ET_DATA-preis is history of price.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the reason you are getting the syntax error is that you would need to update ET_DATA with a work area (structure declared as a line of the same type as the table).

What your code will end up doing though is replacing records in ET_DATA on the second select, on each iteration of your loop, so that will accomplish nothing.

You could most like select everything in one SELECT by using a JOIN:

```
SELECT E1~FIELD1 E2~FIELD2 (etc.)
FROM EPREI as E1
  JOIN EPREIH as E2
   ON E2~PREIS = E1~PREIS AND
      E2~PREISTYP = E2-PREISTYP
into CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ET_DATA.
```

You will just need to change the field specifications in the SELECT clause above to match the fields in your table (and you could leave out the CORRESPONDING).

And you should probably limit the selection on EPREI with a WHERE clause.

Comment: but in ET_DATA-prices is another structure what i want fill by data from EPREIH..